# Getting error when using react-native-google-mobile-ads in expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, admob

When I try to run the project on expo go, I get the following error and the projects refuses to run.

```
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that my `package.json` was not set up correctly. The `react-native-google-mobile-ads` was inside the `expo` section.
It should be as follows:

```
{
  "expo": {
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved on version 12.2.0

[Check this Github comment](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/issues/437#issuecomment-1733063356)